# Deployment in kubernetes shows Back-off restarting failed container while using a docker image created for training images for object detection

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, dockerhub

I have a docker image which was created for training images for object detection.

Here is the dockerfile for my image.

```
FROM python:3

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY /src/ /Training

WORKDIR /Training 

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

To create this container I used

```
sudo docker image build -t training .
```

The container of this image runs fine and I'm able to train on my computer.

I pushed this image to my private docker hub repository using

```
docker tag training abhishekkaranath/training:training


docker push abhishekkaranath/training:training
```

[training image in my private docker hub repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmIeU.png)

I created a secret for my deployment file using

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry hubsecret --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=my_username --docker-password=my_docker_hub_password --docker-email=my_email
```

Below is my deployment.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: podtest
spec:
  containers:
  - name: podtest
    image: abhishekkaranath/training:training
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: hubsecret
```

I created this pod from my terminal using

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

This gave result:

```
pod/podtest created
```

While checking my minikube dashboard I get an error saying "Back-off restarting failed container".

[Back off restarting failed container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp4te.png)

I have tried pulling hello world images from my private docker hub repository into kubernetes which works fine and the pods are up and running. So that means there is no problem in pulling the images from the private docker hub repository.

## Logs and error description:

```
kubectl get pods

NAME      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
podtest   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          20m
```

```
kubectl get nodes

NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
minikube   Ready    master   11d   v1.14.2
```

```
kubectl describe pods podtest

Name:               podtest
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:         Thu, 06 Jun 2019 18:33:02 +0400
Labels:             <none>
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 172.17.0.9
Containers:
  podtest:
    Container ID:   docker://14b9fcc51c8b4a594e0b38580444e2fedd61a636f4e57374d788c9ba5bf9fbcf
    Image:          abhishekkaranath/training:training
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://abhishekkaranath/training@sha256:619468dd0b74b30babfd7c0702c21ea71e9fb70ba3971ec26e8279fdbd071ec7
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 06 Jun 2019 18:54:19 +0400
      Finished:     Thu, 06 Jun 2019 18:54:19 +0400
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  9
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-lb9js (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-lb9js:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-lb9js
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  25m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/podtest to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     23m (x5 over 25m)     kubelet, minikube  Container image "abhishekkaranath/training:training" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    23m (x5 over 25m)     kubelet, minikube  Created container podtest
  Normal   Started    23m (x5 over 25m)     kubelet, minikube  Started container podtest
  Warning  BackOff    4m51s (x94 over 24m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
```

```
kubectl --v=8 logs podtest

I0606 19:03:24.821394    3978 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/abhishekkaranath/.kube/config
I0606 19:03:24.826732    3978 round_trippers.go:416] GET https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/podtest
I0606 19:03:24.826748    3978 round_trippers.go:423] Request Headers:
I0606 19:03:24.826757    3978 round_trippers.go:426]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0606 19:03:24.826764    3978 round_trippers.go:426]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.14.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/b739410
I0606 19:03:24.835800    3978 round_trippers.go:441] Response Status: 200 OK in 9 milliseconds
I0606 19:03:24.835818    3978 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
I0606 19:03:24.835827    3978 round_trippers.go:447]     Content-Length: 2693
I0606 19:03:24.835834    3978 round_trippers.go:447]     Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2019 15:03:24 GMT
I0606 19:03:24.835840    3978 round_trippers.go:447]     Content-Type: application/json
I0606 19:03:24.835870    3978 request.go:942] Response Body: {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"podtest","namespace":"default","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/podtest","uid":"fd87b14c-8867-11e9-a507-0800276a11ac","resourceVersion":"415630","creationTimestamp":"2019-06-06T14:33:02Z"},"spec":{"volumes":[{"name":"default-token-lb9js","secret":{"secretName":"default-token-lb9js","defaultMode":420}}],"containers":[{"name":"podtest","image":"abhishekkaranath/training:training","resources":{},"volumeMounts":[{"name":"default-token-lb9js","readOnly":true,"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"}],"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent"}],"restartPolicy":"Always","terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30,"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","serviceAccountName":"default","serviceAccount":"default","nodeName":"minikube","securityContext":{},"imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"hubsecret"}],"schedulerName":"default-scheduler","tolerations":[{"key":"node.kubernetes.io/not-ready","oper [truncated 1669 chars]
I0606 19:03:24.840211    3978 round_trippers.go:416] GET https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/podtest/log
I0606 19:03:24.840227    3978 round_trippers.go:423] Request Headers:
I0606 19:03:24.840235    3978 round_trippers.go:426]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0606 19:03:24.840241    3978 round_trippers.go:426]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.14.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/b739410
I0606 19:03:24.843633    3978 round_trippers.go:441] Response Status: 200 OK in 3 milliseconds
I0606 19:03:24.843657    3978 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
I0606 19:03:24.843666    3978 round_trippers.go:447]     Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2019 15:03:24 GMT
I0606 19:03:24.843673    3978 round_trippers.go:447]     Content-Type: text/plain
```

```
kubectl get events

LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON      OBJECT            MESSAGE
37m         Warning   BackOff     pod/dhubservice   Back-off restarting failed container
31m         Normal    Scheduled   pod/podtest       Successfully assigned default/podtest to minikube
29m         Normal    Pulled      pod/podtest       Container image "abhishekkaranath/training:training" already present on machine
29m         Normal    Created     pod/podtest       Created container podtest
29m         Normal    Started     pod/podtest       Started container podtest
69s         Warning   BackOff     pod/podtest       Back-off restarting failed container
```

```
docker pull abhishekkaranath/training:training

training: Pulling from abhishekkaranath/training
Digest: sha256:619468dd0b74b30babfd7c0702c21ea71e9fb70ba3971ec26e8279fdbd071ec7
Status: Image is up to date for abhishekkaranath/training:training
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] or any artifacts or logs someone could use to try to debug  your issue?

Comment: please run those commands:
`kubectl describe <your pod>, kubectl logs <your pod>, kubectl get events`
perform `docker pull myrepo.com/myimage:mytag` Please provide the outputs.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've updated the question along with code

Comment: @Hanx I've updated with the required logs

Comment: Hi, [Abhishek Karanath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9003717/abhishek-karanath) could you please share with the results of your investigation?

Answer (score 1):

@Mark is correct. The reason for CrashLoopBackOff is that the container was created it ran /bin/bash as per the CMD in your dockerfile and exited.

If you want container to keep running, you should to execute your python code using:

```
CMD ["python", "-m", "<module_name>"]
```

Another major thing to keep in mind is that container would exit as soon as your app stops. So if app is a dummy code, make sure to run it in a infinite loop to keep the container and app running.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into:

```
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 


    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 06 Jun 2019 18:54:19 +0400
      Finished:     Thu, 06 Jun 2019 18:54:19 +0400
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  9
```

Your pod was scheduled, container was created and finished his job.
As per documentation [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states).