# Cloudera container in Docker exit quickly and map no port

Tags: linux, windows, docker, virtual-machine, cloudera

I'm a freshmen focusing on Database Management System, and I'm using Docker on Windows 10(Newest version), and I use this website https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/ to run a cloudera quick-start container, just printing this code in Powershell(After pulling the image):

```
docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -p 8888 4239cd2958c6 /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

But the container will exit quickly after I run, and I can also get no log( Using `docker log <name>`), no port assigned by docker. And it seems most services(related to the Cloudera Quickstart) are not started, either.

Some pictures here:

[All containers, and the first one is the cloudera,but with no port assigned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zp9w.png)

[There should have been a port like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjtrF.png)

Because the final purpose is to access to Hue interface based on the port, so I do believe I'm in a trouble. And I do need someone's help. Thanks a lot.

P.S. Changing -p 8888:8888 or other port number is useless.

Comment: check if this is the issue you are facing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411631/9092023